# "shutdown worker process after being idea for" IIS setting

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

If I set X minutes for the option ""shutdown worker process after being idea for" in IIS, does it recycle the worker process after X minutes being idea ??

If I use In-Proc session state, will it cause my session being lost?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "idle".  And yes, you will definitely lose your Session data.  Your Session timeout should be less than or equal to your idle timeout.